# How to add quality in FFmpeg video transcoding?

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, transcoding, fluent-ffmpeg

I don't have much knowledge of FFmpeg. I have googled and made the following code for creating two quality hls transcoding for the video files. It is working fine.

I want to create 4 types of video quality. 720,480,320,240.

```
final arguments = '-y -i $videoPath ' +
    '-preset ultrafast -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 ' +
    '-map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 ' +
    '-c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 2000k ' +
    '-c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:1 365k ' +
    '-c:a copy ' +
    '-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1" ' +
    '-master_pl_name master.m3u8 ' +
    '-f hls -hls_time 6 -hls_list_size 0 ' +
    '-hls_segment_filename "$outDirPath/%v_fileSequence_%d.ts" ' +
    '$outDirPath/%v_playlistVariant.m3u8';
```

I am using flutter_ffmpeg (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) plugin to call this code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ya i am using this code in flutter via flutter_ffmpeg-0.2.10 official plugin.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: i want to add two qualities in transcoding. like 720p 480p like this. i dont know how to do it

Comment: In your example you are creating two different outputs with different bit rates, but 720p is a resolution. I don't understand what you mean by adding resolution in the same way as adding bitrate

Comment: yes but i want to create it based on resolution not bit rates. just how youtube shows the option.